# Color calibrate printer/ink/paper using the integrated scanner (without requiring a colorimeter/photometer device)

Tags: printing, scanner, color-management, icc, gnome-color-manager

Ubuntu 15.04 has successfully recognized my *All-In-One printer+scanner Canon PIXMA MG3550* as a *Canon MG3500 series*.

- **Scanning** and **black-and-white printing** are correct :-)
- But **color printing** does not produce the right colors :-(

As I do not find (or I do not know how to find) an [ICC profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) for my system, I tried to understand [printer calibration](https://superuser.com/questions/587166), to use [Argyll](http://www.argyllcms.com/doc/Scenarios.html#PP4) and also to install a GUI ([gnome-color-manager).

But it is too complicated, I am a beginner in color calibration!

Therefore, I am looking for a **simple** intuitive graphical tool to:

1. Print a complete [CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model)
   [color reference test card/chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_chart#Color_reference_charts)
2. Scan the printed result <sub>(assuming the scanner is calibrated)</sub>
3. Compute (and install) the [ICC profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile)
4. Repeat again until the ICC values are sufficiently stabilized

If no such tool exists on Ubuntu, I can download a recommended test image, run some command lines and manually install the new generated ICC profiles. Is there a website briefly providing these steps?

Comment: I am currently struggling with the same topic: printer colors are totally off, even after installing and trying multiple ICC and ICM profiles I got out of the MacOS printer driver. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Hi Jens, I have posted an answer, but I am afraid my answer may not help fixing your issue... Please let me know. Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

#### Solved by upgrading to latest Ubuntu stable release

I have not calibrated my printer but I post here how this issue has been solved as requested by Jens' comment.

In fact, the computer had been repaired by a shop and the **Ubuntu 15.04** I had originally installed had been replaced by the **14.04 LTS** release. As I did not notice the Ubuntu version downgrade I was thinking about a printer calibration problem...

This issue got fixed when migrating from that [Ubuntu LTS release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) to the latest stable release.

As a complement, I can tell a story at my office in 2015: Nobody was able to print on the single printer of the floor from Ubuntu (we were all using Ubuntu LTS). We had to reboot on Windows :-(
One day, I installed the latest Ubuntu stable release, and I became the first to print on that printer :-) (see my [tutorial](https://github.com/olibre/GreatPractices/blob/bffb19a56e3baf372129c3ca41b7e8200d18efff/install/gnu-linux.md#printer)). But I was not using the same official Ubuntu release as my other colleagues...

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the most current release, so this should not be an issue. I had the same issue with 16.04 LTS.

Comment: I understand your printer is old and not yet supported on recent Ubuntu... I am afraid your printer may never be supported because nobody is working any longer on the driver of your printer. I hope I am wrong... Maybe you will be able to test the Ubuntu 18.10. That Ubuntu version should be released at the end of this month...