# Accurate Color Printing using Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: printing, settings, canon, colors

```
 - System  : Ubuntu 18.04
 - Printer : Canon MP287
```

I've spent days trying to get the best settings to get an accurate color printing. No matter what combination I used, the result is extremely different with the source file. I've come across this question [Color calibrate printer/ink/paper using the integrated scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649902/color-calibrate-printer-ink-paper-using-the-integrated-scanner-without-requirin)  but he was using an unstable version of Ubuntu and his solution was upgrading to the latest version of Ubuntu.

Here's comparison between original image and scanned printed result :

[image]

That was printed using Default Setting as bellow :

```
General
Media Size              : A4
Color Model             : RGB Color
Color Precision         : Normal
Media Type              : Plain Paper
Media Source            : Rear Tray
Print Quality           : Standard
Resolution              : Automatic
Srink page If Necessary to Fit Borders  : Shrink (print the whole page)

Printer Feature Common
CD Hub Size             : Normal
Ink Type                : CMKYK
Ink Set                 : Both
Borderless              : No
Orientation             : Portrait

Printer Feature Extra 1
CD Size (Custom)                : 116.1mm
CD Hub Size (Custom)            : 42.7mm
CD Horizontal Fine Adjustment   : 0.0mm
CD Vertical Fine Adjustment     : 0.0mm 

Output Control Common 
Color Correction                : Default
Brightness                      : 1.000
Brightness Fine Adjustment      : 0.000
Contrast                        : 1.000
Contrast Fine Adjustment        : 0.000
Saturation                      : 1.000
Saturation Fine Adjustment      : 0.000
Image Type                      : Mixed Text and Graphics

Output Control Extra 1
Density                         : None
Density Fine Adjustment         : 0.000
Dither Algorithm                : Default
Cyan Density                    : None
Cyan Density Fine Adjustment    : 0.000
Magenta Density                 : None
Magenta Density Fine Adjustment : 0.000
Yellow Density                  : None
Yellow Density Fine Adjustment  : 0.000
Black Density                   : None
Black Density Fine Adjustment   : 0.000

Output Control Extra 2
Composite Gamma                 : None
Composite Gamma Fine Adjustment : 0.000
Cyan                            : None
Cyan Fine Adjustment            : 0.000
Magenta                         : None
Magenta Fine Adjustment         : 0.000
Yellow                          : None
Yellow Fine Adjustment          : 0.000
Black                           : None
Black Fine Adjustment           : 0.000

Cyan Balance                    : None
Cyan Balance Fine Adjustment    : 0.000
Magenta Balance                 : None
Magenta Balance Fine Adjustment : 0.000
Yellow Balance                  : None
Yellow Balance Fine Adjustment  : 0.000

Output Control Extra 4
Linear Contrast Adjustment      : No

Output Control Extra 5
Light Cyan Transition                   : None
Light Cyan Transition Fine Adjustment   : 0.000
Light Magenta Transition                : None
Light Magenta Transition Fine Adjustment: 0.000
Light Yellow Transition                 : None
Light Yellow Transition Fine Adjustment : 0.000
Ink Limit                               : None
Ink Limit Fine Adjustment               : 0.000
GCR Transition                          : None
GCR Transition Fine Adjustment          : 0.000
GCR Lower Bound                         : None
GCR Lower Bound Fine Adjustment         : 0.000
GCR Upper Bound                         : None
GCR Upper Bound Fine Adjustment         : 0.000
```

I have Gutenprint installed and I have checked in

```
usr/local/share/gutenprint/5.2/xml/printers.xml
```

I saw that my printer Canon PIXMA MP287 is listed already. I also have GNOME Color Management installed in my machine but I'm not familiar with it. Is there any settings advice I can follow and apply to my current setting ?

[**UPDATE**]

I tried to calibrate using native printer calibration from Ubuntu. I printed [it8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IT8) target, scan it back and calculate icc profile for correction, setting : Accuracy.  I'm aware that setting preference to accuracy will take longer, but I have 24gb ram and it's been like this for 14 hours now. I'm just gonna cancel it.

[image]

More advice ?

[**UPDATE 2**]

I tried to re-calibrate using [colorchecker passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColorChecker). Process completed and I got a notification that my device is successfully calibrated. However, calibration result is strange.
[image]

Printing result is still as bad as non-calibrated. Still open to suggestions & advice ?